# Dual booting leads to grub menu

Tags: grub2, manjaro, artix-linux

I have a PC with two hard drives. When I bought it, there was Windows 10 on one hard drive and Ubuntu on the other. I replaced Ubuntu with Manjaro, and this was totally fine. When I booted I got a boot menu where I could select either Manjaro or Windows.

Today I decided to replace Windows with Artix. I created a bootable USB with the Artix base openrc. I booted from this drive and followed the instructions found at https://wiki.artixlinux.org/Main/Installation. I didn't get any errors, and everything was successful. However, when I rebooted my computer it boots into a GNU Grub command line like interface. After some searching I found this menu comes up when grub is damaged/can't find operating systems. From this menu I can boot into Manjaro but not Artix - in fact, I still haven't been able to get into Artix except from the bootable USB.

Curiously enough when I go to my PC's BIOS and select the boot drive, there are two options - Manjaro and Grub. Grub takes me to the seemingly useless grub command line or Manjaro. If I select Manjaro my PC boots as it did before and the option in the Manjaro boot menu to boot into Windows is still there (it doesn't work obviously anymore).

How can I fix this so I get a choice between Artix and Manjaro when I boot? I've gone through every single forum regarding grub I can find and probably typed hundreds of commands at this point - nothing seems to actually do anything. Also, is there any comprehensive guide out there for grub/dual booting? All the guides seem to be really poor (think, "just insert your bootable USB and it just works™").

Comment: Are both systems installed in UEFI boot mode, or both in BIOS boot mode? This may work with your live installer, its not just Ubuntu, but for most Linux systems. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

after a bit of probing I managed to figure out the problem

Since Manjaro already had a boot partition there was no need for Artix to have one too. I reformatted the drive, reinstalled Artix without a boot partition. Then I booted into Manjaro, used `pacman -S grub os-prober efibootmgr` and then run the command `grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot --bootloader-id=grub`  and finish with `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

There's probably a better way to do this but this totally works